# OutputText with Converter does not work - why?

Tags: jsf, output, converters

Im trying to convert an Outputtext - simply as that:

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText value="#{someBean.name}"/>
    <h:outputText value="#{someBean.name}" converter="com.java.ee.jsf.TextToStringConverter"/>
    <h:commandButton value="submit" action="#{someBean.doSecond()}"/>
</h:form>
```

ConverterClass:

```
@FacesConverter("com.java.ee.jsf.TextToStringConverter")

    public class TextToStringConverter implements Converter {

        @Override
        public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
            System.out.println("String: " + component);
            return value;
        }

        @Override
        public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
            return (String) value;
        }

    }
```

SomeBean-class:

```
@Model
public class SomeBean {

    private String name;
    private int id;
    private Double someNumber;
    private Date someDate;

blic int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Double getSomeNumber() {
        return someNumber;
    }

    public void setSomeNumber(Double someNumber) {
        this.someNumber = someNumber;
    }

    public Date getSomeDate() {
        System.out.println(someDate);
        return someDate;
    }

    public void setSomeDate(Date someDate) {
        this.someDate = someDate;
    }

public void doSecond() {
        System.out.println("doSecond");
        System.out.println("name: " + name);
        System.out.println("id: " + id);
        System.out.println("someNumber: " + someNumber);
    }
}
```

Im trying to input a string into the Bean property `name` with `<h:inputtext/>` and print that out with  `<h:outputtext/>` but converted with the `TextToStringConverter`. But the converter seems never to be invoked - have I missed something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined the converter for the output text. Therefore, the `getAsString()` method should be invoked. You don’t have a `System.out.println` in this method. Maybe that’s why you are thinking the converter is not invoked.

The code appears to be correct to me.